# Saber quais valores dentro da condição IN que não estão ligados a tabela

Tags: sql, oracle

Olá,

Tenho uma tabela muito simples como exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho também uma query que verifica os valores existentes dentro do IN, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tLetras l WHERE l.letras IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
```

Essa consulta certamente me devolverá todos os valores que estão na tabela `tLetras`.

O que eu preciso, na verdade, é saber quais letras *(valores)* que estão dentro do `IN` e que não estão dentro da `TABLE`. Ou seja, os valores que preciso saber são `'E','H','I','L','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'`, que são justamente os valores que não estão na `TABLE` mas que estão no `IN`.

Comment: Tente utilizar o operador MINUS, é o EXCEPT no Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como a sua lista de letras não está numa tabela, precisa colocar numa "pseudo-tabela", ou "dummy table". O `oracle` tem um recurso interessante para fazer isso que é declarar uma `table` no corpo do select, assim:

```
select *  
  from tLetras  l
  right join table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')) lista on l.letras=lista.column_value
  where l.letras is null
```

Fazendo o `right join` traz os elementos que não existam na esquerda (tabela tLetras ) mas existam na lista da direita. Por fim, o `l.letra is null` traz as letras que não existem, pois vai retornar null onde não coincidir o join

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46a5b7/3)

Aqui a documentação de [odcivarchar2list](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcicnstnts.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível seleccionar algo que não existe na tabela.

O que pode ser feito é ter uma tabela com as letras todas e usar

```
SELECT letra FROM LetrasTodas 
WHERE letra NOT IN (SELECT letras FROM tLetras);
```

Exemplo com **sys.odcivarchar2list**, como sugerido na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/398156/2541) do Ricardo Pontual, mas usando NOT IN em vez de JOIN, o que, neste caso, me parece mais apropriado.

```
SELECT lista.column_value
FROM table(sys.odcivarchar2list('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z')) lista
WHERE lista.column_value NOT IN (SELECT letras FROM tLetras)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dad8bb/1).